# Unknown INPUT tag attribute: CURSOR TRANSMIT

Tags: html, asp-classic

I inherited an ASP classic application created in Visual Studio 6.0, I believe.

There is an INPUT text tag in a form with attributes I don't quite recognize:

```
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="OPERATOR_CODE" SIZE="12" MAXLENGTH="12" TRANSMIT CURSOR>
```

What is this TRANSMIT CURSOR attribute and what does it do?

Comment: Does the page include any Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only in one place, I would probably chalk it up to a typo. TRANSMIT and CURSOR [are not valid input attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) and won't affect the rendering in any major browser.

Comment: Actually, I've seen it in a couple more places in another old ASP Classic application. These are mostly pages called from within Windows CE enabled barcode scanners.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. I assume it's a hook of some sort then to allow the barcode scanners to read/write to these fields. If you have any documentation for the barcode scanners I would take a look at those first.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different attributes - TRANSMIT and CURSOR. Can't help with their meaning through. Might be used by specific page JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know these are not standard attributes. Maybe they were placed there for some other meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It's two separate attributes. It's not some wierd Interdev stuff is it? Perhaps setting the default focus and databinding.

Just a guess though :-)

Comment: The page is for a barcode scanning application in a Windows CE scanner. The page's body contains

<body onLoad="document.GETPASSWORD.OPERATOR_CODE.focus()">

I remove these attributes, but the focus event still occurs... weird attributes.